# thunar-archive-plugin - Failed to extract files: No suitable archive manager found

Tags: centos, archive, thunar

Since we uninstalled ark archiver to use file-roller on Centos 7.4 we are facing an error on thunar with the thunar-archive-plugin.
Any action (extract here, extract to, create archive) give this error message:

```
Failed to extract files: No suitable archive manager found
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way thunar-archive-plugin works is the following.

If you want to extract the file test.tar.gz with a right click in thunar. the process that work in background is the following:

It determines the mime type of the file. You can do it like that:

```
# xdg-mime query filetype /path/to/test.targ.gz
# application/x-gzip
```

It determines the default app for this mime type. You can do it like that:

```
# xdg-mime query default application/x-gzip
# org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop
```

It try to find a thunar-achive-plugin matching this app name.
On Centos 7 those plugins (.tap files) are stored in: /usr/libexec/thunar-archive-plugin/.

Thunar-archive-plugin will the try to find a .tap file according to the default app desktop file name.
For my exemple, the default app is **org.gnome.FileRoller**.desktop, it search then for a tap file named: /usr/libexec/thunar-archive-plugin/**org.gnome.FileRoller**.tap

That's where the problem is. the file roller .tap plugin file is named **file-roller**.tap not **org.gnome.FileRoller**.tap

To resolve this, I simply did:

```
# ln -s /usr/libexec/thunar-archive-plugin/file-roller.tap /usr/libexec/thunar-archive-plugin/org.gnome.FileRoller.tap
```

Just useful to know that .app files are just bash script that you can modify.
You can also create one for your archiver if your's is not yet supported.

Comment: Aslo, see this topic to set the default xdg-mime association: https://superuser.com/questions/1248426/how-to-set-file-roller-aka-file-manager-as-default-for-all-supported-types-i

Comment: I guess it's worth mentioning that you need to do it as sudo. When I pasted your command, there was no error, but the link was not created.